# concurrent saving from two different threads to Core Data persistant store with unique entity Id

Tags: multithreading, core-data, persistence, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I'm implementing multithreaded core data downloader.

I have a problem with doubling objects while saving objects with unique string attribute in Entity.

If 2 threads are downloading from the same url simultaneously (f.e., updater-timer fires and application enters foreground - so user calls update method), I cant check existanse of object with unique attribute value in persistant store, so objects are doubling.

How can I avoid doubling objects and what is the best solution in terms of performance?

description: (sorry, I cant post images yet)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMBgQ.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another approach would be to perform the download/save within an `NSOperation`, and prior to adding an operation to the queue, you could check to see if there was an existing operation to download that URL in the `NSOperationQueue`.

The advantage of this approach is that you don't download any more data than is necessary.

Comment: paulbailey, deanWombourne, thank you. 
I've done task this way, by checking existance of objectForKey: in NSMutableDictionary, where key is [url absoluteString]. 
And the reason why not by deanWombourne numConcurrentOperations=1 is that my CoreDataUpdateManager.h contains an abstract factory for some importers (xml, json, etc.), and manages operations in queue for downloading data for different entities in many threads. 
Not a gallant solution, but it works)

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this before and it's a tricky problem.

I solved it by performing by downloads in separate background threads (the same as you are doing now) but all code data write operations happen on a global NSOperation queue with numConcurrentOperations set to 1. When each background download was complete it created an NSOperation and put it onto that queue.

Good: Very simple thread safety - the NSOperationQueue ensured that only one thread was writing to CoreData at any one point.

Bad: Slight hit in terms of performance because the Core Data operations were working in series, not in parallel. This can be mitigated by doing any calculations needed on the data in the download background thread and doing as little as possible in the Core Data operation.